# In MySQL, how do you automatically set a value for one column when updating another in the same row?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

For the example table below, is there a way to configure the table to auto update the PreviousValue column with the data in the Value column when UPDATE occurs?

```
table Settings
(
    Setting varchar(255),
    Value varchar(255),
    PreviousValue varchar(255)
)
```

Comment: Sure, use [TRIGGER](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html).

Comment: You can do that with triggers: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
CREATE TRIGGER my_trigger BEFORE UPDATE ON my_table FOR EACH ROW
  SET NEW.PreviousValue = OLD.Value;
```

Comment: Thanks. I used this and it worked. I also modified it a bit so that the `PreviousValue` field would only be updated when `Value` is updated (and not when any other field is updated).

IF NOT (NEW.Value <=> OLD.Value) THEN
  SET NEW.PreviousValue = OLD.Value;
END IF

Answer (score 2):

Without trigger, you could also achieve this with below:

```
UPDATE Settings SET PreviousValue = Value, Value = :new_value WHERE Setting = :setting
```

Comment: Yes, but be sure to set `PreviousValue` *before* assigning the new value to `Value` (as @xdazz has done in this example), or else the new value will be assigned to both columns (this yet another example of MySQL's peculiar deviations from standard SQL).